# .htaccess rewrite to subfolder

Tags: apache, .htaccess, apache2, url-rewriting

**The goal:**

In a virtual server on a shared Apache 2.2 box, I've attempted to configure `.htaccess` to seamlessly represent files in a subfolder of the `public_html` folder as if they are in the root.

That is, when the user accesses `http://www.example.com/home`, I need him or her to seamlessly *(without rewriting the URL in the client browser)* see the files from `http://www.example.com/subfolder/home`.

My `.htaccess` file looks like this:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule !^subfolder/ subfolder%{REQUEST_URI}
```

**The problem:**

This works, *but* it rewrites the URL in the client browser.

That is, the user sees `http://www.example.com/subfolder/home/` in their address bar, but I need them to see just `http://www.example.com/home`

My understanding is that what I've done in `.htaccess` should result in an "internal" rewrite that's invisible to the end user, but it appears that I'm getting an "external" rewrite.

What am I doing wrong?

---

**[EDIT] Additional details:**

When the user accesses `www.example.com`, it *does* work as desired, in that the user sees home page content served up from `public_html/subfolder/default.html`, and the browser address bar says `www.example.com`.

However, when the user clicks the 'Contact' link on that home page (coded `href="/contact"`), it gets there, but shows `www.example.com/subfolder/contact/` in the browser address bar, as if it has done a redirect instead of an internal rewrite.

If I then delete the `/subfolder` text in the address bar and force a reload of the page, it works--it loads the correct content, and the address bar remains `www.example.com/contact/`

*Implementation note:* In case it helps, `public_html/subfolder/contact` is a *folder* containing a `default.html` file.

**Another observation:**

If I open a new tab and type `www.example.com/contact/` *(note the trailing slash)*, it works as expected and desired.

But if I open a new tab and type `www.example.com/contact` *(no trailing slash)*, it redirects to `www.example.com/subfolder/contact/`, which is what I don't want.

I feel like that should tell me what's wrong, but the answer still eludes me.

Comment: Do you have any other rules? Are you sure there isn't a trailing slash when you get redirected?

Comment: Are there any files in the public_html directory that you also need to access, or are all files in the subfolder?

Comment: @JonLin, I have no other rules, and yes, there is a trailing slash that I missed, so I edited the question.

Comment: @JennyD, there are not any files in public_html that I also need to access. The `public_html` directory contains the .htaccess file and multiple folders, one of which contains my main `example.com` site, and the others containing subdomain sites.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The reason why this is happening is because of `mod_dir`. It has a directive called `DirectorySlash` that redirects the browser when it thinks a request is made for a directory and the trailing slash is missing to the same URI with a trailing slash appended. The problem is mod_dir and mod_rewrite get applied at different places in the URL/file mapping pipeline. So mod_rewrite mangles the URI at one point, then when mod_dir does its thing, the rewritten URI gets redirected so the URL in the browser's address bar changes to include the "hidden" internal rewrite.

You can do a couple of things here.

1. You can enforce trailing slashes yourself in mod_rewrite, so the browser gets redirected to include the trailing slash *before* the URI reaches mod_dir. This means all of your URLs for things like `/home` and `/contact` will include a trailing slash, if one is missing, your rewrite code will redirect and add one. Something like this, *above* your current rule so that it gets applied first:

   ```
   RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/subfolder
   RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/subfolder%{REQUEST_URI} !-f
   RewriteRule ^(.*[^/])$ /$1/ [L,R=301]
   ```
2. Turn off `DirectorySlash` so mod_dir stops doing this redirect. You can simply include `DirectorySlash Off` at the top of your htaccess file. However, the downside here is [a possible information disclosure security issue](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_dir.html#directoryslash) when the trailing slash is missing.

---

EDIT:

In order to use the index file, without a trailing slash, you need to map to it. Try changing your rules to:

```
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/subfolder
    RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/subfolder%{REQUEST_URI} -d
    RewriteRule ^(.*?)/?$ /subfolder/$1/ [L]

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/subfolder
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /subfolder/$1 [L]
```

Comment: Thanks very much, Jon. Given the simplicity of your solution, the simplicity of the site, and my lack of security concerns, I like option #2. When I add `DirectorySlash Off` to the head of .htaccess, I start getting `Forbidden` failures on all pages other than the homepage. The server error log shows a lot of `Directory index forbidden by Options directive` failures. Thoughts?

Comment: Do I understand correctly that your edit presents an "option #3" that is not to be combined with `DirectorySlash On`?

Comment: @briguy328 No, you leave `DirectorySlash Off`, but you need to add a trailing slash to the internal rewrite so the auto-index doesn't kick in.

Comment: Thanks! That's closer, in that the correct pages always load with the desired URLs in the address bar, but now none of the images load. The error logs show that there are now slashes appended to the ends of image file names (e.g. `/images/header.jpg/` instead of `/images/header.jpg`)

Comment: @briguy328 This seems more complicated than before, see the edit above

Comment: That works! I'm very impressed and grateful, Jon. I'm still learning Stack Overflow--can I do more for you than to simply accept your answer?

Comment: @briguy328 I think the only things you can do is click on the check mark and upvote

Comment: @JonLin Great answer +1. I was looking for this everywhere.